# Cleaner way to whiten each image in a batch using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to whiten each image in a batch.  The code I have to do so is this:

```
def whiten(self, x):
    shape = x.shape
    x = K.batch_flatten(x)
    mn = K.mean(x, 0)
    std = K.std(x, 0) + K.epsilon()
    r = (x - mn) / std
    r = K.reshape(x, (-1,shape[1],shape[2],shape[3]))
    return r
#
```

where x is (?, 320,320,1).  I am not keen on the reshape function with a -1 arg.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what the `-1` does. From the Tensorflow documentation (Because the documentation from Keras is scarce compared to the one from Tensorflow):

> If one component of shape is the special value -1, the size of that dimension is computed so that the total size remains constant.

So what this means:

```
from keras import backend as K

X = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
K.reshape(X, [-1, 5])
# Add one more dimension, the number of columns should be 5, and keep the number of elements to be constant
# [[1 2 3 4 5]]

X = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6])
K.reshape(X, [-1, 3])
# Add one more dimension, the number of columns should be 3
# For the number of elements to be constant the number of rows should be 2
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]]
```

I think it is simple enough. So what happens in your code:

```
# Let's assume we have 5 images, 320x320 with 3 channels
X = tf.ones((5, 320, 320, 3))
shape = X.shape

# Let's flat the tensor so we can perform the rest of the computation
flatten = K.batch_flatten(X)
# What this did is: Turn a nD tensor into a 2D tensor with same 0th dimension. (Taken from the documentation directly, let's see that below)
flatten.shape
# (5, 307200)
# So all the other elements were squeezed in 1 dimension while keeping the batch_size the same

# ...The rest of the stuff in your code is executed here...

# So we did all we wanted and now we want to revert the tensor in the shape it had previously
r = K.reshape(flatten, (-1, shape[1],shape[2],shape[3]))
r.shape
# (5, 320, 320, 3)
```

Besides, I can't think of a cleaner way to do what you want to do. If you ask me, your code is already clear enough.

Comment: You made the mistake of missing that I specified keras, not tensorflow.

Comment: Updated my code with Keras. Previously I was importing the keras.backend directly from Tensorflow so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Also, where did you find the "-1" documentation. I've had so much trouble with keras in finding this stuff in their documentation.

Comment: Final suggestion: When the documentation from Keras has a lack of details for the module you need always try to find the same thing in the Tensorflow's documentation. The -1 is an example:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape

Comment: I think im going to abandon keras and switch fully to tf.keras or pytorch. Thanks again.

Comment: According to the tf.keras overview, "Detailed documentation and user guides are available at keras.io."  This is very confusing.